# How to aggregate log-likelihood score of many models?

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models, likelihood, validation, scoring-rules

I have a process through which I estimate the parameters of a model in order to make predictions. Through this process, I end up with many models (with different parameter values) that are then used to make predictions on their relevant cohorts (for example different companies, regions, etc.). The purpose of this process is to avoid fitting one model to many different datasets that would likely contain many different distributions. I'm thinking about using something like out of sample log-likelihood to score my predictions - I've considered methods such as MSE but would like to capture the uncertainty of my parameter estimates in the scoring process. My question is about how would I go about aggregating the final log-likelihood scores of each of these models into one score to use for comparison against other modeling techniques (model selection/comparison).

I understand that I could simply compare the relevant individual model scores across modeling techniques, as in, by comparing the same cohort. But I'd like to find a way to compare all models in aggregate.

Answer (score -1):

Can you maybe give some example how your "different datasets" look like? Are the predictors & the target variable the same in all datasets?

Shot from the hip: Why don't you add the categorical features for "company", "region", etc. to your model and train only a single model on all the data?

Besides, you should rather compare the *marginal likelihood* a.k.a. *model evidence* (= expected likelihood under the prior) instead of the bare likelihood. Otherwise you are prone to choose an overfitted model.